# Any good online chart generators?

Tags: charts

I am looking for some free site that allows you to easily create a chart from provided data (in interactive mode, so I don't have to write any code) and export it to an image. Can anyone recommend anything good?

Thanks.

Comment: Offtopic? Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found [charts.hohli.com](http://charts.hohli.com/), looks like it is built on top of google charts, but at least has nice interactive interface. That's pretty much what I am looking for, if there is no better options.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)

Comment: It's an API. I am looking for something interactive with GUI.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Doc](http://google.com/docs) Spreadsheets have a Chart GUI.

Just go to `Insert` and select `Chart`

Once it's setup, you can Right-click on your chart and select `Publish Chart`

Answer (score 0):

[EditGrid](http://www.editgrid.com/) does exactly what you want.

Comment: Not really. It looks like an overkill (I dont' need spreadsheets only charts) plus doesn't allow you to export charts into images, instead you have to embed some widget (at least it is what it says in demo).

Comment: Oh, I assumed you need the whole shebang. In that case, yeah, it might be overkill. But last time I used it, it did save your charts as downloadable images, although I'll admit that was about a year ago.