# Good chart drawing software?

Tags: charts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application to help build diagrams](https://superuser.com/questions/67536/application-to-help-build-diagrams)

I'm looking for a program, which I can use to draw good and smooth-looking charts. I would prefer it to be free, but it is another problem :)

What can you recommend?

**EDIT:**

By charts I mean the same as Wikipedia does: [Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chart)

Also, I think I need off-line application, not online (but would be happy to look at them, if they are good)

Comment: Off topic. Anyway, on Linux, you'll find `Dia` for chart, but I tend to prefer raw `Inkscape` vector graphics.

Comment: Off-topic. What exactly do you mean by "chart" though, Diagrams? I know a great tool for those

Comment: also related: [Any good online chart generators?](http://superuser.com/questions/30188/any-good-online-chart-generators)

Answer (score 2):

> [GnuPlot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) is a portable command-line
>   driven graphing utility for linux, OS/2, MS Windows, OSX, VMS, and
>   many other platforms. The source code is copyrighted but freely
>   distributed (i.e., you don't have to pay for it). It was originally
>   created to allow scientists and students to visualize mathematical
>   functions and data interactively, but has grown to support many
>   non-interactive uses such as web scripting. It is also used as a
>   plotting engine by third-party applications like Octave. Gnuplot has
>   been supported and under active development since 1986.
>
> Gnuplot supports many types of plots in either 2D and 3D. It can draw
>   using lines, points, boxes, contours, vector fields, surfaces, and
>   various associated text. It also supports various specialized plot
>   types. Demos here.
>
> Gnuplot supports many different types of output: interactive screen
>   terminals (with mouse and hotkey input), direct output to pen plotters
>   or modern printers, and output to many file formats (eps, fig, jpeg,
>   LaTeX, metafont, pbm, pdf, png, postscript, svg, ...). Gnuplot is
>   easily extensible to include new output modes. Recent additions
>   include an interactive terminal based on wxWidgets and the creation of
>   mousable graphs for web display using the HTML5 canvas element.

[image: pie map]

[image: chart]